# Adding legends to Axes3D plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, mplot3d

I'm trying to add a legend to a 3D plot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (12, 10)
fig = plt.figure(1)
plt.clf()
ax = Axes3D(fig, 
           rect = [0, 0, .95, 1],
           elev = 48, 
           azim = 134,
           )
plt.cla()


ax.scatter(df_labeled['frequency'], df_labeled['recency'], df_labeled['monetary'], 
          c = df_labeled['label'],
          s = 200,
          alpha = 0.5,
          edgecolor = 'darkgrey',
          label = df_labeled['label'].unique()
          )

colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green']

ax.set_xlabel('Frequency', 
             fontsize = 16)
ax.set_ylabel('Recency',
             fontsize = 16)
ax.set_zlabel('Monetary',
             fontsize = 16)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

And I ended up getting this:
[image]

The legend is incorrectly displaying one color and in a list rather than 3 separate legends for each label. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by plotting each color separately, then legend will have an entry for each plot you made. Here is a minimal example with 2 plots:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpy.random import rand

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

n = 100

ax.scatter(rand(n), rand(n), rand(n), label='Plot 1')
ax.scatter(rand(n), rand(n), rand(n), label='Plot 2')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]